# Play Store listing

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

How do I get my application on the play store like this on top of all these things which is in the red box?

[image]

But I got my application like this so how do I manage this.

[image]

Can anyone help me with how this thing works?

Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question

Answer (score 1):

`There's no special way of doing` it just type the exact name of the app
like I typed and got this for your app ,it works as your app becomes more popular

[image]

Comment: So there is no such way for a new application right?

Comment: I don't know so bcoz I tried this with a 9 month old app with about 1k downloads and typed the exact name of the app and it shows a proper app layout for it like you asked

Comment: Can you share the app name so I can check?

Comment: @Gaurav I think it works for all when you type the exact name of the app coz on play store you can't have **apps with same name**

Comment: Thanks for help I will check.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to what you're describing (that can be done manually) is an Interstitial play store advert I believe. Otherwise the only way to achieve this is to enter the exactly app or package name for your listing.

Have a look at the docs here:
https://ads.google.com/intl/en_uk/home/campaigns/app-ads/
https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6357635?hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Cinterstitial-ads%2Cbanner-ads

Hopefully that helps

Comment: No this is not an ads thing. but I think this is a listing process to reach your application with some keywords. I think this way.

Comment: There's no specific way of doing that. You can promote an app as a banner ad or get this my using the exactly name of the app or package name. That's it really.

Comment: I will try like this.